# File-dialog box to create/save a new file in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I have following code to file-open-dialog-box :

```
(define fname (get-file))
```

However, this only shows existing files for opening. How can I open a file "save" dialog-box, where there is a possibility of putting a new file name for file creation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[put-file](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/Windowing_Functions.html?q=put-file#%28def._%28%28lib._mred%2Fmain..rkt%29._put-file%29%29)

A filler line to reach at least 30 characters.

Comment: I do not know why I could not reach this documentation page. Thanks.

Comment: I find that (define fname (get-file)) works but not (define fname (put-file)). Can this be solved?

Comment: What did you see? What happened? What did you expect?

Comment: I forgot to put  "/gui" in #lang racket/gui. It works.